# SQLPlus - Stored procedure that displays the number of items sold in descending order

Tags: sqlplus

I'm in a bit of a bind - I want to make a stored procedure that displays the number of each item sold and orders them from most to least. The relevant data comes from two different tables:

```
ITEMS  | itemid | itemname
SALES  | itemdid
```

I can display the itemid and count of each item sold with this query:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT ITEMID, 
COUNT (ITEMID) AS COUNTOF
FROM SALES GROUP BY ITEMID
ORDER BY COUNTOF DESC);
```

I can display the `itemname` of each item sold with this one:

```
SELECT ITEMS.ITEMNAME
FROM ITEMS
JOIN SALES
    ON SALES.ITEMID = ITEMS.ITEMID;
```

However, I can not seem to get the `itemname` to display next to the count of the item sold. I'm really struggling with this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a JOIN or INNER JOIN.

```
SELECT s.ITEMID,i.ITEMNAME,  COUNT (s.ITEMID) AS COUNTOF FROM SALES AS s
INNER JOIN ITEMS AS i ON i.itemid=s.itemid 
GROUP BY s.ITEMID,i.ITEMNAME
ORDER BY COUNTOF DESC
```